# HTML5 Create a post request passing JSON OBJ in a PHP page and load the new php page

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest

I am playng with HTML5, Javascript,JSON and PHP, I am a beginner

I am creating a web page with the list of articles in PHP read from MYSQL, I want to click on article and open a new PHP page

I succeed to do it by my own,I copied here and ther from internet, I also succeed to create a JSON object and pass it to XMLHttpRequest to a PHP page, I don't get why it not open a web page

here the piece of code from list.php where I create a JSON object collecting data from the selected row clicked by mouse from table created with PHP from mysql:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "article.php");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 

   if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) { 

       console.log(xhr.responseText); // it wrotes the article.php page in console

    } 

   }

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

here the code from article.php

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

I see the result of working article.php in the chrome console! no web page loaded!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is very simple, you may be able to use:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("POST", "article.php")
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.documentElement.outerHTML = xhr.responseText
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this is a very limited hack. There are a number of ways in which things could go wrong.

A better approach may be to define a form and a field with the JSON text, and submit that, instead of using XHR.

Comment: Hello I tryed to change the line :

console.log(xhr.responseText);

with your :

document.documentElement.outerHTML = xhr.responseText

but I got  :

lista_articoli2.php:158 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element's parent is of type '#document', which is not an element node.
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost/TestMagazzino/lista_articoli2.php:158:72)

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of misunderstanding with xmlhttprequest, it isued to retrive information

I created an hidden form, and on click handler i set value of each input type and after that a document.getElementById("form").submit();

this part of code :

```
<form id="formInvio" action="dettaglio.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" id="idkey" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="partNumber" id="idpartNumber" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="descrizione" id="iddescrizione" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="prezzo" id="idprezzo" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantita" id="idquantita" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="ubicazione" id="idubicazione" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="note" id="idnote" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="idsubmit">
</form>
```

and this is where i set value and generate click :

```
  function addRowHandlers() {
        var table = document.getElementById("articoli");
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = table.rows[i]; //servirà sotto alla fine
            var createClickHandler =
                function (row) {
                    return function () {
                        var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
                        // ciclo su tutti i td della cella
                        var accrocchio = 0;

                        for (let cell of cells) {
                            var id = cell.innerHTML;
                            //alert(id.innerText);
                            switch (accrocchio) {
                                case 0:
                                    document.getElementById("idkey").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    document.getElementById("idpartNumber").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    document.getElementById("iddescrizione").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    document.getElementById("idprezzo").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    document.getElementById("idquantita").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 5 :
                                    document.getElementById("idubicazione").value = id;
                                    break;
                                case 6:
                                    document.getElementById("idnote").value = id;
                                    break;
                            }
                            accrocchio++;
                        }
                        document.getElementById("formInvio").submit();

                    };
                };

            currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
        }
    }
```

in main php page i put this code to hidden submit button and to add handler onlick funzion on table :

```
    <style style="text/css">
        #articoli {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        #articoli td {
            padding: 7px;
            border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
        }

        /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
        #articoli tr {
            background: #b8d1f3;
        }

        /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
        #articoli tr:hover {
            background-color: #ffff99;
        }

        #idsubmit {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

    </style>

window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

I hope it can help someone that want to create a list of article in php and onclick on the row open a detailed page ...